# Componentes primefaces não aparecem

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Pessoal boa tarde já tentei de tudo mudar a url do web.xml para *.xhtml mas ele não vai, adicionei a biblioteca primefaces no lib do WEB-INF, mas os componentes não aparecem.

Meu web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-
app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value><!--Developmente or Products-->
</context-param>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>
    30
 </session-timeout>
</session-config>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

Meu Cadastro.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
     <title>Cadastro de Cliente</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#
 {request.contextPath}/cssPrimeFaces/default.css" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#
 {request.contextPath}/cssPrimeFaces/principal.css" 
    />
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#
    {request.contextPath}/cssPrimeFaces/theme.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
           .ui-layout-north {
                  z-index:20 !important;
                 overflow:visible !important;;
            }

          .ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
                overflow:visible !important;
           }
    </style>
    </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
      <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="header">
        <ui:insert name="top">
         <h:panelGroup id="header_top">
             <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="container">
                <b:column col-sm="6">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="contactinfo">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +2 95 01 88 821</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> info@domain.com</li>    
         </ul>     
    </h:panelGroup>  
 </b:column>
                    <b:column col-sm="6">
                 <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="social-icons pull-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><i class="fa fa-facebook" action="" ></i></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-twitter" action=""></i></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" action=""></i></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" action=""></i></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" action=""></i></li>
</ul>
                     </h:panelGroup>
             </b:column>
             </h:panelGroup>    
         </h:panelGroup> 
        </ui:insert>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="header-middle"><!--header-middle-->
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="container">
     <b:row>
         <b:column col-sm="4">
             <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="logo_pull_left">
                 <h:commandLink action="index.xhtml">
               <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="winnerlogo.png"/> 
                 </h:commandLink>

          </h:panelGroup>

         </b:column>
          <b:column col-sm="8">
             <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="shop-menu pull-right">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i><h:commandLink action="#{navegacao.redirecionarConta()}" value="Minha Conta" /></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><h:commandLink action="#{navegacao.redirecionarCarrinho()}" value="Carrinho de compras" /></li>

    <li><i class="fa fa-lock"></i><h:commandLink action="#{navegacao.Login()}" value="Login" /></li>
    </ul>

    </h:panelGroup>

         </b:column>
     </b:row>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

```
          </b:column>
        <b:column col-sm="3">


            <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" id="busca" class="search_box" />
        </b:column>

                  <b:column col-sm="4"> 

    <h2>Informações Pessoais</h2>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="login-form2">
        <h:outputLabel for="Email" styleClass="Email" value="Email:  "/> <p:inputText styleClass="email2"  value="#{cliente.cli.email}"/><br/>
        <h:outputLabel for="Nome" value="Nome:  " id="nome"/><p:inputText styleClass="nome"  value="#{cliente.cli.nome}"/>
```

```
 <p:commandButton value="Salvar " styleClass="salvar"  action="#{cliente.cadastroCliente()}"  /> <p:commandButton value="Salvar " styleClass="salvar" action="#{clienteBean2.Cadastrar()}" /> <p:commandButton value="Salvar " styleClass="salvar" action="#{clienteBean2.Cadastrar()}" />
```

```
                    </h:panelGroup> 
                </b:column>

                <b:column col-sm="4">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="login-form">     
                        <h:outputLabel for="rua" value="Rua: "/> <p:inputText id="rua" styleClass="rua" value="#{cliente2.rua}"/><br/>
                        <h:outputLabel for="numero" value="Numero: "/> <p:inputText id="numero" styleClass="numero" value="#{cliente2.numero}"/><br/>
                        <h:outputLabel for="bairro" value="Bairro: "/> <p:inputText id="bairro" styleClass="bairro" value="#{cliente2.bairro}"/><br/>
```

```
     </b:row>
 </h:panelGroup>
  </h:panelGroup><!--header-bottom-->
    </h:panelGroup>



   <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="footer">

    <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="footer-top">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="container">

          <b:row>
                    <b:column col-sm="1"></b:column>          
        <b:column col-sm="8">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="companyinfo">

        <h2><h:panelGroup  styleClass="">e</h:panelGroup>-shopper</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
</h:panelGroup>
        </b:column>  



                 <b:column col-sm="3">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="address">

    <img src="images/home/map.png" alt="" />
<p>505 S Atlantic Ave Virginia Beach, VA(Virginia)</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
         </b:column>

            </b:row> 

           </h:panelGroup>
           </h:panelGroup>


        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="footer-widget">
       <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="container">

          <b:row>
           <b:column span="2">
             <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="single-widget">

        <h2>Serviços</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>Online Help</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>Order Status</li>
        <li>Change Location</li>
        <li>FAQ’s</li>
        </ul>

                    </h:panelGroup>
    </b:column>
              <b:column col-sm="3">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="single-widget">
    <h2>Categorias</h2>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mens</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Womens</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
        </ul>
         </h:panelGroup>
</b:column>
    <b:column col-sm="2">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="single-widget">
                <h2>Politicas</h2>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="single-widget">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Terms de Uso</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Politica de Privacidade</a></li>
        </ul>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </b:column>
        <b:column col-sm="2">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="single-widget">
        <h2>Sobre</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Company Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Affillate Program</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
        </ul>
        </h:panelGroup>
                    </b:column>


        </b:row>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="footer">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="footer-bottom">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block"  styleClass="container">


                <b:row>

<p class="pull-left">Copyright © 2013 E-SHOPPER Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
<p class="pull-right">Designed by <span><a target="_blank" 
        href="http://www.themeum.com">Themeum</a></span></p>
        </b:row>
     </h:panelGroup>

      </h:panelGroup>


  </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGroup>
   </h:form>
  </h:body>
 </html>
```

Como minha pagina esta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você leu sua postagem? Não da pra entender o código. Está sem identação, o mesmo código está quebrado em vários blocos de formatação de código, tem conteúdo estranho no meio da postagem... Assim fica difícil ajudar.. Edita a pergunta incluindo o código identado. Não precisa ser a perfeição, mas pelo menos deixe um pouco melhor de ler, por favor. Aí acredito que terá mais change de conseguir a resposta desejada :-)

Comment: pronto editei agora esta mais visivel

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar o jar por aqui...

Em cima do projeto clica com o botão direito do mouse e vai em **Build Path** em seguida **Configure Build Path**, na tela que abriu, na aba **Libraries** vai em **Add External JARs..**, e adiciona o jar do prime faces. Depois de ter adicionado o jar, na coluna do lado esquerdo vai em **Deployment Assembly**, clica no botão **Add..** e em seguida clica no Java **Build Path Entries** e seleciona o jar do prime faces, e depois de ter adiciona o jar vai em **Apply** e pronto.

Comment: então man eu adicionei o jar na lib da web-info

Comment: mas não sei porque os compomentes não aparecem, e desculpe não entendi adicionar o jar aqui ?

Comment: Pois é, só colar o jar na lib não funfa direito. Adiciona o jar por esse passo a passo e testa.

Answer (score -1):

Ás vezes o que pode ocorrer, de não aparecer alguns componentes na tela do JSF,ou até mesmo todos os seus itens, pode ser também que na url seja necessário acrescentar o /faces/pagina.xhtml

Ex.:

http://localhost:8080/projetojsf/faces/Cadastro.xhtml